# azure-ad-b2c wrong location

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-virtual-machine

I created a B2C with Location being Canada.  but as you can see from the image, it came to united states. Why did this happen?

[b2c active directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UaMj.jpg)

Comment: It also says "Canada" under "Country or Region" - there must be some difference between "Location" and "Country or Region"...?

Comment: Yes you are right, but I assume that the location should be Canada as well. That is what i selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a by design behavior.
Azure AD B2C is **generally available worldwide** with the option for **data residency in United States or Europe**.

**Region availability** refers to where a service is available for use.
**Data residency** refers to where user data is stored.

> Data resides in the **United States** for the following countries/regions:
>   United States, **Canada**, Costa Rica, Dominican Republic, El Salvador,
>   Guatemala, Mexico, Panama, Puerto Rico and Trinidad & Tobago
>
> Data resides in **Europe** for the following countries/regions:
>      Algeria,
>   Austria, Azerbaijan, Bahrain, Belarus, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia,
>   Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Egypt, Estonia, Finland, France,
>   Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Israel, Italy, Jordan,
>   Kazakhstan, Kenya, Kuwait, Lativa, Lebanon, Liechtenstein, Lituania,
>   Luxembourg, Macedonia FYRO, Malta, Montenegro, Morocco, Netherlands,
>   Nigeria, Norway, Oman, Pakistan, Poland, Portugal, Qatar, Romania,
>   Russia, Saudi Arabia, Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia, South Africa, Spain,
>   Sweden, Switzerland, Tunisia, Turkey, Ukraine, United Arab Emirates
>   and United Kingdom.

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tenant-type).